# Rspec - How to create macros with tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec3

Is there a way to run Rspec macros conditionally ?

For example ability to filter macros using

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding :broken => true
end

## This should get skipped
it_should_validate_with_macro :some_param, :broken => true
```

**Note:** This is to invoke group of tests dynamically. So `pending` kinda solution is not I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "an example" do
  it "is implemented but waiting" do
    pending("something else getting finished")
    this_should_not_get_executed
  end
end
```

from https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples

Comment: Yes im aware about `pending`. But I wanted to invoke group of tests dynamically. So this not gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run specs in the same process, and you can also do things like [capture the output](http://jing.io/t/programmatically-execute-rspec-and-capture-result.html).

But a simple example that might work for you is simply to create a ruby script:

```
require 'rspec/core'

RSpec.configuration.add_setting(:some_setting)
RSpec.configuration.some_setting = false
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec/models/bar.rb'])
RSpec.clear_examples
if RSpec.configuration.some_setting
  RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec/models/foo.rb'])
end
```

Then, in your rspec script that will modify the setting:

```
RSpec.describe 'bar' do
  it 'bar' do
    RSpec.configuration.some_setting = true
  end
end
```

This will conditionally run the spec in `foo.rb`.